# How to make jumping smooth?

Tags: godot, gdscript

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    direction = Vector3.ZERO
    if !is_on_floor():
        direction -= transform.basis.y
    if Input.is_action_pressed("mf"):
        direction -= transform.basis.z
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("b"):
        direction += transform.basis.z
    if Input.is_action_pressed("JUMP") and is_on_floor():
        direction += transform.basis.y
        direction = move_and_slide(direction * 100, Vector3.UP)
    direction = direction.normalized()
    direction = move_and_slide(direction * speed, Vector3.UP)
```

This is my movement. But my character teleports into air and slowly falls down. How do I make the jumping smooth?

Answer (score 0):

You need gravity, always. What works for me is to have the kinematic body fall before the jump code.

```
extends KinematicBody
var speed=10
var gravity = 10
var jump_speed = 10
var vertical_velocity = Vector3.ZERO
var direction=Vector3.ZERO

func _physics_process(delta):
    # fall
    vertical_velocity += gravity * delta * Vector3.DOWN
    vertical_velocity = move_and_slide(vertical_velocity, Vector3.UP)

    # jump code
    if is_on_floor() and Input.is_action_pressed("JUMP"):
        vertical_velocity = jump_speed * Vector3.UP
    
    direction=Vector3.ZERO
    if Input.is_action_pressed("mf"):
        direction-=transform.basis.z
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("b"):
        direction+=transform.basis.z
    direction = direction.normalized()
    direction = move_and_slide(direction*speed, Vector3.UP)
```

Note that the above code allows you move normally while on the air. I don't know if you want that or not.

---

Here is a version that will keep direction on the jump, but not let you change it mid air:

```
extends KinematicBody
var speed=10
var gravity = 10
var jump_speed = 10
var vertical_velocity = Vector3.ZERO
var direction=Vector3.ZERO

func _physics_process(delta):
    vertical_velocity += gravity * delta * Vector3.DOWN
    vertical_velocity = move_and_slide(vertical_velocity, Vector3.UP)
    if is_on_floor():
        if Input.is_action_pressed("JUMP"):
            vertical_velocity = jump_speed * Vector3.UP
        if Input.is_action_pressed("mf"):
            direction-=transform.basis.z
        elif Input.is_action_pressed("b"):
            direction+=transform.basis.z
        else:
            direction=Vector3.ZERO
        direction = direction.normalized()
    
    direction = move_and_slide(direction*speed, Vector3.UP)/speed
```

Note that this code will only set `direction=Vector3.ZERO` when `is_on_floor()` and no there is no directional input.

---

That also means that the `speed` factor would accumulate, which is why I divide by it.

We could instead introduce the factor here:

```
        direction = direction.normalized() * speed
```

And then we can have this:

```
    direction = move_and_slide(direction, Vector3.UP)
```

*At which point the name `direction` is not accurate. Since it have speed incorporated. I would call it `horizontal_velocity` or `ground_velocity`.*